# Parallax Scrolling With Finite Length

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk, parallax

I have a side scrolling platformer that uses Chipmunk and Cocos2d for iPhone. The player moves from one side of the level to the other side of the level to complete the level. The player actually moves from one side to the other; the background is not repeated to create the illusion of scrolling.

However, I have been befuddled as to how I could do this with a parallax background. The level goes to about 3000 on the x coordinate.I cannot use an image that large. I also cannot make the image repeat itself after the player reaches a certain point because the player is not standing in one location.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the background image into 3 images, each 1024 pixels in width. Simply offset the 2nd and 3rd image sprite's position by 1024 times 2 respectively times 3.

Comment: The CCParallaxNode will allow such large images? And I can make 3 CCParallaxNodes? I tried this but I don't think I was able to make more than one parallax nodes.